# OpenMP parallelize a random sequence

Tags: c, openmp

I want to parallelize a loop that have a sequence of random numbers generated by the function erand48. The order of the sequence is important so I can't change it. I tried this:

```
   #pragma omp parallel for
   for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
       printf("%f \n",erand48(vector));
   }
```

But the order of the sequence changed. Any suggestion??

Comment: OpenMP cannot turn automagically an intrinsically sequential code to a parallel one.

Answer (score 1):

If the order of execution is important, you can't parallelize the loop.  When it is parallelized, the 2nd iteration could run before the 1st one.

You could generate all of your random numbers, store those in an array, then run the parallel loop accessing the array.

Comment: The problem is that if I generate an array the size is so big and it go out of memory (process is killed)

Comment: You can try breaking it up into chunks.  Have an outer loop that serially generates a batch of random numbers, then the parallel loop to process those.  Then you loop back and generate the next batch of random numbers.  Continue until you've done the whole thing.